# Does Aragon OSX have a url for polygon subgraph?

Tags: dao, subgraph, governance

I only see goerli subgraph in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Mainnet**

- Current

  - https://subgraph.satsuma-prod.com/qHR2wGfc5RLi6/aragon/osx-mainnet/api

**Goerli**

- Current

  - https://subgraph.satsuma-prod.com/qHR2wGfc5RLi6/aragon/osx-goerli/api

**Sepolia**

**Polygon**

- Current

  - https://subgraph.satsuma-prod.com/qHR2wGfc5RLi6/aragon/osx-polygon/api

**Mumbai**

- Current

  - https://subgraph.satsuma-prod.com/qHR2wGfc5RLi6/aragon/osx-mumbai/api